# Why button[type="submit"] only work as direct child of form

Tags: html

If I write one `<button type="submit" ..>` within a form, the form is submitted once the button has been pressed.

now I want but the button is not a direct child, **but not works**

```
<div class="form-component">
    <div class="form-header">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
    <div class="form-content">
        <form method="post">
            <div class="form-element"> <!-- ... --></div>
            <div class="form-actions">
               <button type="submit">Save</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code posted does not reproduce the problem. Please post code that does, and identify the browser(s) in which this can be observed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does work. See http://jsfiddle.net/kJtMG/
Most likely you have invalid HTML somewhere in the parts you have commented.

```
<div class="form-element"> <!-- ... --></div>
```

Comment: yeah. in the template i have `button`

Answer (score 0):

if `input` of type `submit` is a child of your form, the form will submit by just clicking on the button. Like this :

```
<form method="post">
        <div class="form-element"> <!-- ... --></div>
        <div class="form-actions">
           <button type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

If not, you can force form submit by `javascript/jquery`:

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-element"> <!-- ... --></div>
</form>

<div class="form-actions">
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</div>
```

The jquery:

```
$('button[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).prev('form').submit();
});
```

or this (using form id) :

```
$('button[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e){
    $('#form_id').submit();
});
```